# Android Studio NDK: use prebuilt opensll libraries - error finding include files

Tags: android-studio, build, openssl, android-ndk, include-path

I dowloaded Android studio and NDK (Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Patch 3) and compiled and run the "Hello Word" CPP example project successfully on my Android phone.
Great!
Now I want to use openssl functions and methods in my project.

I downloaded a prebuilt Android binaries from: https://teskalabs.com/blog/openssl-binary-distribution-for-developers-static-library and now want to include the static libraries and header files in my project.

In Android Studio I created an "include" folder where I copied all *.h files from dowdloaded openssl folder. I also added `include_directories(src/main/cpp/include)` in CMakeList.txt.
Lastly I added line `#include <ssl.h>` to native-lib.cpp - nothing else, no openssl function etc.
When I try to make my project I get a compile error: `fatal error: 'ssl.h' file not found`. If I take out the "include" line everything compiles and runs fine. I also tried `#include "ssl.h"`- same error.
I am using Windows 10.
My project tree looks like this:

```
...
v main
  |
  cpp
    |
    > include
    CMakeList.txt
    native-lib.cpp
...
```

If I open the "include" tab it has all the ssl.h etc files.

What am I doing wrong? Why does Android Studio find the header files?

Answer (score 0):

After 3 days of trying and trying and afer posting the question I finally found what the problem was in my case.
Instead of using:

```
include_directories(src/main/cpp/include)
```

I used this:

```
include_directories(include)
```

Now it links